# l/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl-impersonate-chrome: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, alpine-linux

when I tried to install `curl-cffi>=0.5.9` in python3.10 in docker, shows error like this:

```
#12 50.74 gcc -shared 
#12 50.74 build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/curl_cff
#12 50.74 i._wrapper.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/curl_cffi/ffi/shim.o 
#12 50.74 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lcurl-impersonate-chrome -o 
#12 50.74 build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/curl_cffi/_wrapper.abi3.so
#12 50.74 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-mus
#12 50.74 l/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl-impersonate-chrome: No such file or directory
#12 50.74 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
#12 50.74 error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
#12 50.74 
#12 50.74 See /tmp/pdm-install-g3swgott.log for detailed debug log.
#12 50.74 [InstallationError]: Some package operations are not complete yet
#12 50.74 Add '-v' to see the detailed traceback
#12 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c pdm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

this is the docker file look like:

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine3.18

MAINTAINER jiangxiaoqiang (jiangtingqiang@gmail.com)

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    TZ=Asia/Shanghai

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
    && mkdir -p /root/visa \
    && apk update \
    && apk add gcc wget curl vim musl-dev libstdc++ curl-dev g++

RUN pip install pdm
ADD . /root/visa/
WORKDIR /root/visa/
RUN pdm install
ENTRYPOINT exec /root/visa/scripts/startup-app.sh
```

what should I do to fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Build curl-impersonate-chrome - https://github.com/lwthiker/curl-impersonate/blob/main/Dockerfile.template

Or use it lwthiker/curl-impersonate:0.5-chrome docker image